# How to create an if statement that will notify the user that the index chosen is higher than the max index in a tuple?

Tags: python, if-statement, tuples

I have a tuple with 4 items, meaning the highest index is 3. I am trying to create an if statement that will tell the user an item doesn't exist if the index they chose is higher than the max index in the tuple (in this case, more than 3). In the screenshot, this is currently what I have. It obviously doesn't work.

```python
inventory = ("sword,",
             "armor",
             "shield",
             "healing potion")

max_index = max(len(x) for x in inventory)

index = int(input("\nEnter the index number for an item in inventory: "))
if index > max_index:
    print("This index does not exist.")
else:
    print("At index", index, "is", inventory[index])
```

Comment: Please post your code as plain text, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are finding the length of each string. Instead call length on the tuple itself:

```py
inventory = ("sword,",
             "armor",
             "shield",
             "healing potion")

index = int(input("\nEnter the index number for an item in inventory: "))
if index > len(inventory) - 1:
    print("This index does not exist.")
else:
    print("At index", index, "is", inventory[index])
```

Alternatively you can use a try except:

```py
inventory = ("sword,",
             "armor",
             "shield",
             "healing potion")

index = int(input("\nEnter the index number for an item in inventory: "))
try:
    print("At index", index, "is", inventory[index])
except IndexError:
    print("This index does not exist.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `max_index` is calculating the maximum length of the strings in the list, not the maximum index of the list.

List indexes go from 0 to 1 less than the length of the list, so just base it on the length.

```
max_index = len(inventory) - 1
```